# Center Group of divs in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row that can contain 3-5 divs. The divs need to be horizontally (left/right) centered. On-click the divs 'flip' to show additional information. The centering is working fine except when flipped, then it appears the divs height gets changed and they are no longer vertically aligned. If I add 'float:left' on line 24 in the CSS that issue goes away, but then they are no longer centered horizontally

https://jsfiddle.net/rffxmbh0/1/

```
#readModal>.modal-lg {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

#readModalContent {
    height: 420px;
}

.row-center {
    text-align:center;
}

#readModal h2{
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.col-centered {
    padding:0;
}

.whatToReadCover {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    height: 350px;
    width: 255px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;

    text-align: center;
}

.whatToReadCover p,
.whatToReadCover .description {
    width: 170px;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin:0;
}

.cover {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.cover-image {
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.whatToReadCover .description {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 17;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    //height: 290px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 238px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.whatToReadCover:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.whatToReadCover:last-child {}

.more-info {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 162px;
    border: 2px solid #20638f;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    color: #20638f;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.vertical-align: top` to your `.whatToReadCover` elements. This is important for keeping elements at the same position on the y-axis when using `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Use these styles in your divs:

```
    border: 1px solid #09f;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: What divs? Where are the borders, heights and widths coming from?

Comment: No matter, the important is 'vertical-align' and 'display' properties

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding display:flex to your .row-center class.

```
.row-center { text-align:center; display: flex; }
```

Not 100% sure by your question if you want 2 separate rows, but this fixed the awkward vertical alignment issue for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/ow1n0gz9/

Comment: thanks for the input DL, but adding display: flex prevents the divs from being centered inside the row. .vertical-align: top fixed the issue